# How do I fetch all the rows available without a while in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, select, loops

If I wanted to fetch multiple ROWS without doing the while loop like this:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {}
```

how can I do that in mysql and php?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php#90030  Still uses a `while`, but is short and simple.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to insert in my $_SESSION a query that contains all the rows of a cart list for a spicific user

Comment: Be coherent to what you want and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` is intended to fetch a single row from a resultset, so there is no reasonable way not using a while. Use mysqli with fetch_all or get used to while :)

Your comment:

```
$_SESSION["whatever"]=array();
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
   array_push($_SESSION["whatever"], $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With mysqli you have a [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function. From the manual:

> mysqli_result::fetch_all -- mysqli_fetch_all — Fetches all result rows
>   as an associative array, a numeric array, or both